# Git clone fails over HTTPS on Linux VM (Inflate: Data Stream Error)

Tags: git, github, https, clone, virtualhost

I tried to clone multiple github repos (e.g Node.js repo) via HTTPS using Xubuntu and Lubuntu VMs as guests on Windows 10 to no avail since it fails with a data stream error:

```
fatal: pack has bad object at offset 610504: inflate returned -3
fatal: index-pack failed
```

The error changes across multiple runs of the same command. However, using SSH works fine. The error seems to be related to zlib (source: https://superuser.com/questions/1067443/git-pack-has-bad-object-when-pushing-to-remote).

Also, I don't know if it may be related to using the "default" network mode of VirtualHost (NAT).

I tried to clone said repos on the host machine and it worked fine both through HTTPS and SSH.

I used Xubuntu 18.04 and git 2.27. Virtual Box version is 6.1.10.

Comment: I am having the problem too.  Surprised there's no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own answer:

It seems like the problem has been fixed but it is not clear to my what was the actual fix. I'm currently using:

- Windows 10 Pro, Os Build 19041.685.
- Docker for windows Version 3.3.0 (62916) with WSL2

  - Engine 20.10.5
- Xubuntu 18.04 on the guest machine.
- Virtual Box 6.1.18 with the guest additions installed.

as Joachim Schiele answered, disabling Hyper-V is a workaround in case you face this issue. However, as far as I know, it is up and running and I'm not having this problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague just informed me that they disabled hyperV and then it worked. They were using Windows 10, some recent Virtualbox version on Windows and the NAT adapter to get the Debian VM online.

Seems to be realted to network and checksum offloading computation.

Sorry, don't have more details.